# Deleting nodes from large XML files

Tags: c#, xml

i have a large XML document that is to large to be loaded using XmlDocument. i need to go through each child of a node and check it agaisnt a condition, then delete accordingly , then finally save the document.

```
<root>
<node id="1">
<child delete="false"/>
</node>
<node id="2">
<child delete="true"/>
</node>
</root>
```

for example i would want to delete node 2, and this process must be repeated hundreds of times.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

**Edit**
could someone explain how i might go about doing this.

Comment: Hundreds of times is not a lot. Regardless - what is your question? A call for help doesn't tell us what you are having problems with.

Comment: whats your condition? can you not use linqxml query to extract elements to be delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) to sequentially read your xml ([`ReadOuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml.aspx) might be useful in your case to read a whole node at a time). Then use an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) to write out all the nodes you want to keep.

Comment: XmlReader for me too, saves reading teh large file into memory in one lump.

Answer (score 0):

See this article which compares the performances of xml parsing approaches- http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html

XmlReader turns out to be winner here..

Answer (score 0):

Note, untested and I haven't used `XDocument/XElements` for awhile, so there may be a typo in here

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("path\\to\\file.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsToDelete = xdoc.Descendants("node")
   .Where(node => node.Descendants("child")
       .Where(child => child.Attribute("delete") != null && 
       child.Attribute("delete").Value.ToLower() == "true"));
foreach(XElement element in elementsToDelete)
    element.Remove();

xdoc.Save("path\\to\\new\\file.xml");
```

Comment: But the real file.xml is "too large to be loaded using XmlDocument"

Comment: @HenkHolterman ooh, missed that part. This will load the entire file into memory, so probably not what the OP wants.